# problema al instalar pytube en python3.8.2 32 bit en windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

quiero instalar pytube y pongo

```
pip install pytube
```

no tengo mas de 1 python asi que no hay error

pero al importarlo en algun programa me sale

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/santiago/Desktop/python/Pythobe.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pytube
  File "C:\Users\santiago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pytube.streams import Stream
  File "C:\Users\santiago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\streams.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pytube import extract
  File "C:\Users\santiago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pytube.compat import quote
ImportError: cannot import name 'quote' from 'pytube.compat' (C:\Users\santiago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\compat.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pytube` no es compatible con Python 3.8, no ahora mismo, instala [Pytube3](https://pypi.org/project/pytube3/) en su lugar, pero desinstala primero `pytube`:

```
python -m pip uninstall pytube
python -m pip install pytube3
```

el error se debe a `urllib2.quote` que en Python 3.x se movió a `urllib.parse.quote`. Faltan importaciones en el caso de que se ejecute en Python 3 en el módulo `compat.py` (`lib\site-packages\pytube\compat.py`), el problema se corrige modificando dicho archivo para incluir los imports necesarios:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# flake8: noqa
"""Python 2/3 compatibility support."""
import sys


PY2 = sys.version_info[0] == 2
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3
PY33 = sys.version_info[0:2] >= (3, 3)

if PY2:
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")
    import urllib2
    from urllib2 import URLError
    from urllib2 import quote
    from urllib2 import unquote
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    from urlparse import parse_qsl
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

    def install_proxy(proxy_handler):
        """
        install global proxy.
        :param proxy_handler:
            :samp:`{"http":"http://my.proxy.com:1234", "https":"https://my.proxy.com:1234"}`
        :return:
        """
        proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy_handler)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    def unescape(s):
        """Strip HTML entries from a string."""
        html_parser = HTMLParser()
        return html_parser.unescape(s)

    def unicode(s):
        """Encode a string to utf-8."""
        return s.encode("utf-8")


elif PY3:
    from urllib import request
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from urllib.parse import quote, urlencode, parse_qsl, unquote


    def install_proxy(proxy_handler):
        proxy_support = request.ProxyHandler(proxy_handler)
        opener = request.build_opener(proxy_support)
        request.install_opener(opener)

    def unicode(s):
        """No-op."""
        return s

    if PY33:
        from html.parser import HTMLParser

        def unescape(s):
            """Strip HTML entries from a string."""
            html_parser = HTMLParser()
            return html_parser.unescape(s)

    else:
        pass
```

No obstante, instala PyTube3 y no te compliques.

Reporte sobre el problema en GitHub:

- https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/591

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con.

```
$ pip install pytube3
```

Checa la documentacion si es compatible con la version de python que tienes instalada, tambien checa si tienes permisos como administrador en la linea de comandos cuando lo instales.